# How to get certain bits of a char array to another char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

I have a char (input) array with size 60. I want to write a function that returns certain bits of the input array.

```
char  input_ar[60];

char output_ar[60];

void func(int bits_starting_number, int total_number_bits){

}

int main()
{

input_ar[0]=0b11110001; 

input_ar[1]=0b00110011; 

func(3,11);

//want output_ar[0]=0b11000100; //least significant 6 bits of input_ar[0] and most significant bits (7.8.) of input_ar[1]

//want output_ar[1]=0b00000110; //6.5.4. bits of input_ar[1] corresponds to 3 2 1. bits of  output_ar[1] (110)  right-aligned other bits are 0, namely 8 7 ...4 bits is zero


}
```

I want to ask what's the termiology of this algorithm? How can I easily write the code? Any clues appricated.

Note: I use XC8, arrray of bits are not allowed.

Comment: I recommend you use `unsigned char` instead of `char` to avoid problems shifting the MS bit.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you want or how you are referring to bits. You pass `bits_starting_number = 3` yet the example shows you started at bit 5. Did you mean the third bit from the left? In which case, what is your bit order? The first comment refers to bits 7,8 so are you using a 1-base? The second comment correctly refers to bits 5,4,3, but why have you shifted the first byte left by 2 bits and the second byte right by 3 bits? Confused.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it a bit confusing, sorry for that. MSB is first bit, and called (1. bit). LSB is the last bit (called 8. bit) [for this contex]. There is an error at second line, it should be 6. 5. 4. I corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer makes the following assumptions. Bits are numbered from 1, the first bit is the MS bit of the first byte. The extracted bit array must be left-aligned. Unused bits on the right are padded with 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_LEN 60
#define BMASK   (1 << (CHAR_BIT-1))

unsigned char  input_ar[MAX_LEN];
unsigned char output_ar[MAX_LEN];

int func(int bits_starting_number, int total_number_bits) {
    // return the number of bits copied
    int sors_ind, sors_bit, dest_ind = 0;
    int i, imask, omask;
    memset (output_ar, 0, MAX_LEN);         // clear the result
    if (bits_starting_number < 1 || bits_starting_number > MAX_LEN * CHAR_BIT)
        return 0;                           // bit number is out of range
    if (total_number_bits < 1)
        return 0;                           // nothing to do
    bits_starting_number--;
    if (bits_starting_number + total_number_bits > MAX_LEN * CHAR_BIT)
        total_number_bits = MAX_LEN * CHAR_BIT - bits_starting_number;
    sors_ind = bits_starting_number / CHAR_BIT;
    sors_bit = CHAR_BIT - 1 - (bits_starting_number % CHAR_BIT);
    imask = 1 << sors_bit;
    omask = BMASK;
    for (i=0; i<total_number_bits; i++) {
        if (input_ar[sors_ind] & imask)
            output_ar[dest_ind] |= omask;   // copy a 1 bit
        if ((imask >>= 1) == 0) {           // shift the input mask
            imask = BMASK;
            sors_ind++;                     // next input byte
        }
        if ((omask >>= 1) == 0) {           // shift the output mask
            omask = BMASK;
            dest_ind++;                     // next output byte
        }
    }
    return total_number_bits;
}

void printb (int value) {
    int i;
    for (i=BMASK; i; i>>=1) {
        if (value & i)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
    }
    printf (" ");
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    input_ar[0]= 0xF1;  // 0b11110001
    input_ar[1]= 0x33;  // 0b00110011 

    printf ("Input:  ");
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
       printb(input_ar[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    func(3,11);

    printf ("Output: ");
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
       printb(output_ar[i]);
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
Input:  11110001 00110011 00000000 00000000
Output: 11000100 11000000 00000000 00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the returntype: You can return a boolean array of length total_number_bits.

Inside your function you can do a forloop, starting at bits_starting_number, iterating total_number_bits times. For each number you can divide the forloopindex by 8 (to get the right char) and than bitshift a 1 by the forloopindex modulo 8 to get the right bit. Put it on the right spot in the output array (forloopindex - bits_starting_number) and you are good to go

This would become something like:

```
for(i = bits_starting_number; i < bits_starting_number + total_number_bits; i++) {
    boolarr[i - bits_starting_number] = charray[i/8] & (1 << (i % 8));
}
```